# limiting adding object in array in actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

i just beginer in as3, i got little problem with array and object (movieclip). first if you want add object into array use `array.push(object)` is't it? and if you want remove it with `array.splice(index, 1)`. then how about stop adding object to array if you want just 10 object in array if my code just like this one?

```
private function RandomEnemy():void {
    var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy(RandomRange(700, 1000), 350);
    enemy.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, RemoveFromArray);
    layerChar.addChild(enemy);
    enemies.push(enemy);
}

private var remaining:int = 10;
private function RemoveFromArray(e:Event):void {
    removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, RemoveFromArray);
    var index:int = enemies.indexOf(Enemy(e.currentTarget), 0);
    enemies.slice(index, 1);
    remaining--;
    trace(remaining);
    if (remaining==0) {
        //stop the adding object in array
    }
}
```

sorry for my bad english, and i still don't know how programming with as3 and flash.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the length property of the array to see how many items are in it.

```
enemies.length
```

You can then do whatever you want based on that value. Looking at your code, it looks like you should put the entire thing in an if block to check if there are any items in the array before trying to remove from it.

Perhaps something like this is what you want?

```
private function RemoveFromArray(e:Event):void {
    // not quite sure what you were trying to do with this line...
    removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, RemoveFromArray);

    // check to see if there are any items in the enemies array to remove
    if (enemies.length > 0){
        var index:int = enemies.indexOf(Enemy(e.currentTarget), 0);
        //enemies.slice(index, 1);
        // splice() is what you may actually want, as it adds/removes elements from the array
        enemies.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
        trace("No more items in enemies array.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You could also create custom wrapper around the array, that checks the length of the array before adding anything to it

2) Take a look at the Vector class, you can fix its length, and it is more efficent than Arrays in many cases.

3) if the object you wish to remove is at the begining or end of the array, don't use splice, use pop or shift, as splice is very expensive

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the simplest solution is to check if the array has 10 elements before adding objects:

```
if (enemies.length < 10){
    layerChild.addChild(enemy);
    enemies.push(enemy);
}
```

Also, it seems like you misspelled `splice` in `enemies.slice(index, 1)`. And I know that you're new and all, but it's best if you stick with as few functions as possible to avoid confusion.

Going off of Neil's points, Vectors are generally superior to Arrays, but don't fix the length of your Vectors since you're not going to have only 10 elements in them (unless you want to stray from your comfort zone, but efficiency isn't an issue here). And do use splice since, again, efficiency isn't a problem in this case.